# Hyperledger orderer <-> peer connection breaks after a while on MS Azure

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have 2 different machines in cloud.

Containers on first machine:

```
orderer.mydomain.com
peer0.org1.mydomain.com
db.peer0.org1.mydomain.com
ca.org1.mydomain.com
```

Containers on second machine:

```
peer0.org2.mydomain.com
db.peer0.org2.mydomain.com
ca.org2.mydomain.com
```

I start them both. I can make them both join the same channel. I deploy a BNA exported from hyperledger composer to both peers. I send transactions to peer0.org1.mydomain.com and query and get same results from peer0.org2.mydomain.com.

Everything works perfectly so far.

However after 5 - 10 minutes peer on second machine (peer0.org2) gets disconnected from the orderer. When I send transactions to org1 I can query them from org1 and I see the results. But org2 gets detached. Doesn't accept new tx. (orderer connection gone) I can query org2 and see old results.

I added CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=30 to my peer env variables. I see keep alive actions in org2 peers logs. But didn't solve my problem.

I should note: Containers are in a docker network called "basic". This network was used in my local computer. However it still works in cloud.

In orderer logs:

```
Error sending to stream: rpc error: code = Internal desc = transport is closing
```

This happens every time I try. But when I run these containers in my local machine they keep connected without problems.

EDIT1:  After checking the logs: peer0.org2 receives all tx and sends them to orderer. Orderer receives requests from peer but can't update peers. I can connect to both requestUrl or eventUrl on the problematic peer. There is no network problem.

Comment: Please provide the configuration (environment variables, etc) of the peers.
Also if you can successively reproduce the problem, could you provide a tcpdump trace log for us to analyze?

Comment: @yacovm I added all config and docker compose files to my question upon your comment.

Comment: to be it sounds like something that worth report about to the project JIRA: https://jira.hyperledger.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I found the problem. It is about MS Azure networking. After 4 minutes azure cuts idle connections:

https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/115005583008-Azure-Networking-Connection-idle-for-more-than-4-minutes

EDIT1:

Yes the problem was about MS Azure.. If there is anyone out there trying to run hyperledger on Azure keep in mind that if peer stays idle for more than 4 minutes azure times out tcp connections. You can configure it to timeout in 30 mins. It is not a bug but it was annoying for us not being able to understand why it wasn't working after 4 mins.

So you can use your own server or other cloud solution or use azure by adapting to their rules.

Comment: Is there a github repo of your configuration of fabric network to learn from? Please share.